# How to iterate over datatable and remove duplicates in dropdown values of each row?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to iterate over each row in a datatable and remove duplicate values from dropdown which is present in each row. It only removes duplicates from 1st row dropdown. Rest all remains as is with duplicate values. Can someone please help?

**HTML**

```
<table id="myTable" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="10" width="100%" style="font-size:12px">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th><input name="select_all" value="1" type="checkbox"></th>
         <th>Standard Comments</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      {% for result in results %}
      <tr>
         <td>
            <select id="standardcomments" class="select">
               <option value={{result['STANDARD_COMMENTS']}}>{{result['STANDARD_COMMENTS']}}</option>
               <option value="None">None</option>
               <option value="FollowUp">FollowUp</option>
               <option value="ABCD">ABCD</option>
               <option value="ABCD">ABCD</option>
               <option value="EFGH">EFGH</option>
               <option value="IJKL">IJKL</option>
               <option value="MNOP">MNOP</option>
               <option value="QRST">QRST</option>
            </select>
         </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".select option").val(function (idx, val) {
            $(this).siblings('[value="' + val + '"]').remove();
        });
    });

</script>
```

**Javascript using .each()**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#standardcomments option').each(function () {
                    if ($.inArray(this.value, optionValues) > -1) {
                        $(this).remove()
                    } else {
                        optionValues.push(this.value);
                    }
                });

            });
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you happen to know about [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)?

Comment: Yes, tried using it...But didn't work either. Posted the script above.

Comment: Looks like you are duplicating the id for `#standardcomments` that could cause an issue

Comment: I am looping in the results of {{result['STANDARD_COMMENTS']}} from database. So creating the drop downs with id standardcomments in a loop. So that, each row in the data table has a dropdown with option values.